# Getting a single value insted of array?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am trying to get department name using

```
$('#DropDownListDepartment').select2({ data: DeparmentDesc });
```

The ddl shows each charecter in the name of department as different option.
[image: The image shows output for Information Technology]

Comment: It's showing you `DeparmentDesc`.  That's what that variable contains.  If you find yourself asking *"why is it doing this wrong?"* then answer is usually *"It isn't.  You are."*

Comment: It looks like the data source that you populate the dropdown with is a string (`DeparmentDesc`), it should be an array instead, [see the docs](https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays).

Comment: `.select2({ data: [DeparmentDesc] });` - would that work?

Comment: thanks for help. I have figured out the issue and solved the problem. i used the same code as Fran has suggested.

Comment: @AbdulBasitMehmood Keep a bookmark to the doucumentation handy it has all the code examples: https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I got solution for this. I replaced

```
$('#DropDownListDepartment').select2({ data: DeparmentDesc });
```

to

```
$('#DropDownListDepartment').select2({ data:[ DeparmentDesc] });
```

And it is working according to my requirment.